# SQL Outer join using connect and level by

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

SQL join on several tables for existenance of records on a specific condition

**Table - A**

```
PID     Date        COL-A   COL-B
11      01-APR-13   AA      BE
11      03-APR-13   DD      BE
22      03-APR-13   EW      BD
33      01-JUN-13   AR      B7
11      20-APR-13   AS      AS
```

**Table - B**

```
PID     Date        COL-A   COL-B
11      01-APR-13   AT      BW
22      04-APR-13   AG      BD
11      07-APR-13   AD      BW
33      08-MAY-13   AG      BF
```

**Table - C**

```
PID     Date        COL-A   COL-B
11      01-APR-13   AG      BR
22      02-APR-13   AR      B3
33      03-APR-13   A3      BY
44      01-APR-13   AB      BY
```

Query # Tables with records would have Y or N at least if one of the table have a records matching the criteria where PID in (11,22) and date range between 01-APR-13 and 07-APR-13

Output would be something like

```
PID     Date            Table - A       Table - B       Table - C
11      01-APR-13       Y               Y               Y
22      02-APR-13       N               N               Y
11      03-APR-13       Y               N               N
22      03-APR-13       Y               N               N
11      07-apr-13       N               Y               N
```

I know I can outer join the tables but I guess how I can scan through the date range ? I guess I can use level and connect by from oracle 11g to get range of dates.

Update # i've several tables that I need to combine in this nature to get corresponding Y and N values for each of those tables. That being said, I am not sure if Union is a good option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want a range of dates, you actually want a list of your `pid`s. If you have 3 tables with these in I hope you have a fourth "master" list, which all of these have foreign keys into. Failing that you have to create that list yourself. Creating a list of dates would simply mean that you have a lot of dates with missing additional information.

Your full query would end up looking something like this:

```
with pid_list as (
        -- Generate list of all PID/date combinations
 select pid, date
   from tablea
  union
 select pid, date
   from tableb
  union
 select pid, date
   from tablec
        )
select pl.pid, pl.date
     , case when a.pid is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end as tablea
     , case when b.pid is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end as tableb
     , case when c.pid is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end as tablec 
  from pid_list pl
  left outer join tablea a
    on pl.pid = a.pid
   and pl.date = a.date
  left outer join tableb b
    on pl.pid = b.pid
   and pl.date = b.date
  left outer join tablec
    on pl.pid = c.pid
   and pl.date = c.date
       -- Restrict date ranges from list of PIDs to that required
 where date between to_date('yyyymmdd', '20130401') 
                and to_date('yyyymmdd', '20130407')
       -- Enforce condition that PID must exist in one of the tables
   and exists ( select 1
                  from pid_list
                 where pid in (11, 22)
                   and date between to_date('yyyymmdd', '20130401')
                                and to_date('yyyymmdd', '20130407')
                       )
```

I assume that the actual columns name is not DATE, as this is a reserved word.

Comment: Union of all tables to get pid and date? Is this efficient if I were to use the same logic to combine 15-20 tables. Each of these tables are having at least 15 years worth of data. Any suggestions?

Comment: No, it's not at all efficient. The 15 years of data is immaterial. What matters is things like number of records and server power... Having said all that, what choice do you have? You need that list somehow and if you're not actively maintaining it you have two options. 1. Start actively maintaining it. Have a materialized view that creates it or do so yourself whenever you enter a new record. 2. Do what I've suggested and create it on the fly...